# mimic s3cmd list folder in php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, s3cmd

what function/technique in aws phpsdk which equals with s3cmd ls s3://

i have the files uploaded into s3, which structure:

```
folder_a/file_a.ext
folder_a/file_aa.ext
folder_b/file_b.ext
folder_b/file_bb.ext
```

I need to list first the folder without the all file names which can be done in s3cmd, but I want to do it in php

Answer (score 0):

There is [get_bucket_list()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_bucket_list) wich lists the buckets in you S3, and there is [get_object_list()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list) wich gives you a list of objects in a bucket.

For further uses see the [API documentation here.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=AmazonS3)

Hope that this is what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

IF you just want the file names then you can loop through the results you get and use [PHP basename() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Comment: I've tried phpsdk functions. basically I just want to have result list of [folder_a, folder_b], not all-files-full-path-name

Comment: the folder_a and folder_b are buckets or objects in buckets?

Comment: those are objects, its directories, if you use s3cmd you'd know